# How do I get past the hologram room in the Sierra Madre Vault?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I seem to be stuck in the Sierra Madre hologram room (the one just before entering the Vault).  I've rerouted the hologram patrols, disabled the alarms, but I can't figure out how to lower the force field to advance to the next part of the vault.  Did I miss something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick Walkthrough on how to get through the third floor and into the Vault (I think this is what you're looking for):

> From the doorway where you enter this
>   room, on the opposite side of the
>   room, there's a long enclosure that
>   runs most of the length of the
>   opposite wall, plus a very small
>   enclosure in the right corner. The
>   doorway to exit this room is between
>   these 2 enclosures, and one of the
>   holograms is standing guard next to
>   it.
>
> There's also a medium-sized enclosure
>   on the far-right wall that has a
>   terminal that controls the Hologram
>   next to the exit. Also, on your right
>   as you come into the room, there's
>   stairs going down to a lower catwalk
>   level. The Cloud is covering this
>   lower catwalk level, and you have to
>   jump from the bottom of the stairs to
>   the next section of this catwalk.
>
> Also note the metal supports overhead.
>   The hologram emitters are on top of
>   the supports, but walking on them can
>   be a little tricky, especially when
>   the holograms turn hostile and start
>   shooting you after you take out any of
>   the emitters. To get to the overhead
>   supports, jump on top of the far-right
>   enclosure from the main catwalk.
>   There's steps leading up to the
>   supports from the top of the
>   enclosure.
>
> As you turn the corner after exiting
>   the hologram room, your collar will
>   start beeping as you run toward a
>   speaker on the wall ahead of you.
>
> This terminal lets you deactivate the
>   weapon turrets and the blue
>   forcefields around the Vault, allowing
>   you to get into the Vault. But
>   deactivating the security also
>   triggers the entire sequence of events
>   leading up to the confrontation with
>   Elijah, including locking the elevator
>   out of here until Elijah actually
>   comes down to the Vault. So, switching
>   off the security is basically a point
>   of no return.
>
> You'll see 2 folders regarding the
>   Vault's security. Back out of the
>   folder and you'll now see a 3rd option
>   to disable the Vault's security
>   protocols.

Comment: Thanks, but it's the "exiting the hologram room" that I'm having trouble with.  There's a forcefield blocking the exit.  Is there a way to disable it, or does it come down based on a trigger?

Comment: I was trying not to spoil anything, but when you turn off the security Elijah will come down and confront to player. He opens the forcefield.

Comment: The room I'm stuck in is the one just before I (presumably) get to the final vault room.  There are 3-4 Hologram guards, and a bunch of catwalks above poisonous gas.  Is that the point where I need to disable security to have Elijah confront me?  I thought the point you refer to occurs after the room I'm stuck in.  If we are talking about the same thing, how do I disable security?  The emitters?  Could I have missed a terminal?

Comment: Ahh, found it.  I missed the fact that when you disable the alarm, a new option pops up to disable the force field.